# jQuery keeps number of cloned rows after reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form in a popup, that presents a simple table with header and one row, with a + button the user can click to add (clone) a row.

This works perfectly, the user submits the form, data is read - no problem.
The form is reset  after submission with:

```
   $('#entryTable').find("tr:gt(1)").remove(); // keep header and first row
   $('#entryForm')[0].reset();
```

If the user calls the form immediately, the forms "seems" correctly reset, all fields look like new.
If the user clicks on the + (clone) button - it adds the number of rows added previously, and not 1, as if something (but what ?????) was not reset.

my clone function is

```
 $(".cloneprod_add").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $tr  = $(this).closest('.tr_clone'); //only first row has +
  var idtr= parseInt($tr.attr("id"));   // checked it is always id of row1
  var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
  cindex++;
  $clone.find(':text').val('');
  $clone.attr('id', idtr+(cindex) );  
  $clone.find("*").each(function() {
        var id = this.id || "";
        var match = id.match(regex) || [];
        if (match.length == 3) {
            this.id = match[1] + (cindex);
        }
  });
  $tr.after($clone);
  $("#addline_"+cindex).addClass("uk-hidden"); // remove +
  $("#delline_"+cindex).removeClass("uk-hidden");  // add -
  });
```

cindex is correctly reset to 0 when the form is called again. What else should be reset ? where is my error ?
Thanks for your advices

(EDIT)
I am adding the form . I am using UIkit (www.getuikit.com), a node server and the form comes from a template in jade - I copied the HTML from the browser

```
<form id="entryForm" action="" class="uk-form uk-form-stacked" >
<div id="entryDialog" class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-dialog-large">
<fieldset data-uk-margin="">
<div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-panel-box-primary uk-margin-small-top">
<div class="uk-form-row"><div class="uk-grid"><div class="uk-width-1-1">
<table id="entryTable" class="uk-table">
  <thead><tr><th>lot</th><th>code</th><th>num</th>
   <th>qte</th><th>unit</th><th>pos</th><th>cont</th>
   <th></th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody><tr id="0" class="tr_productclone">
    <td><input type="text" name="lot" id="lot_0" class="lot"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="code" id="code_0" class="code"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="num_0" id="num_0" class="num"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="qte_0" id="qte_0" class="qte"></td>
    <td><select name="unit_0" id="unit_0" class="unit"><option value="items">pezzi</option></select></td>
    <td><select name="pos_0" id="pos_0" class="pos"><option value="1">piece1</option></select></td>
    <td><select name="cont_0" id="cont_0" class="cont"></select></td>
    <td><button id="addline_0" class="uk-button cloneprod_add"></button>
      <button id="delline_0" class="uk-button cloneprod_del"></button></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody></table></div></div></div></div>
 <div class="uk-modal-footer"><button id="btnSave" type="submit" class="uk-button ">save</button></div>
  </fieldset></div></form>
```

Comment: Can you also show the HTML code here, just the form part?

Comment: can you add it to https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: this is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/prtome/ztokz491/8/
I copied the code, but it does not work, and I don't know how to make it work in jsfiddle, i got rid of uikit but it seems not to find jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. I don't know the why and hows, but at least it works.

I had the impression that the remove was keeping the information of the number of cloned rows and was thus putting that number back. I thought about reloading the table in the modal, so that it would be "fresh without memory".

In the end, I wrote the definition of the table in the js script and not in the Jade template. The table is rebuilt overtime the form is called, and no more memory ghosts.

It works, but I still don't understand why those ghosts.